# Angularjs download function using url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a download function in my angularjs using a url link ( not a json )
For example: https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/historicsites.zip
How can i do so ?

PS: Another question @the comment

```
 <button ng-click="download">
 </button>
```

Comment: use a `download` attribute: `<a href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/historicsites.zip" download>`

Comment: oh wow cool, thanks. Just another question, is it possible to change the url after the /shp/  like  https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/abc.zip (abc.zip) to https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/def.zip (def.zip)

Comment: On page load, suppose from x place you are getting this dynamic `url` then assign `URL` in a variable and bind it in a `href` attribute.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating more on that? @UtkarshDubey please and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use download attribute in `<a>` tag

```
<a href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/historicsites.zip" download>
```

If you want to change the url, do

```
<a ng-href="https://assets.onemap.sg/shp/{{fileName.zip}}" download>link1</a>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! But i am getting this error on my console log, any idea how to fix it? "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip:"